# php substitute for shell's find+fgrep(+touch)

Tags: php, shell, templates

I need to change the last edit date to a select number of files.
Troughout my directory tree I have directories called `templates`. For the sake of this question, I dont know the exact location.

What I want is the following:
- find all files in directories called `templates`, which contain one or more `keywords`
- change the last edit date to now.

I can do this with shell, using a `find`, combined with `fgrep`, combined with `touch`. This would be a very fast method. However, my employer prefers a non-shell method.

I'm looking for a way to do this in **php**, but it has to be **very fast**. Is there a method for this?
I'm avoiding the method where I loop through all directories recursively, loop through those files in them to open them just to check if they contain 1 or more keywords.

Comment: `system('find /root -path "*/templates/*'.$keyword.'*" -exec touch {} \;');`?

Comment: Im looking for a substitute for the commandline, not for the command :)

Comment: You're asking for a golden sheep with 5 legs. Doing this entirely in native PHP is going to be noticeably slower than using native shell functionality with optimized C/C++ calls inside. You can have either shell-based and fast, or PHP-based and slow. Pick one.

Comment: I am aware of the difference, but as mentioned before, my employer prefers a php method, because of security reasons

Comment: `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` together with some regex/string testing or `FilterIterator` and `touch` then. It's simply never going to be as fast as `find` though. You will have to decide whether it's *fast enough*.